# Composition of functions and operator forms of built-in functions

Tags: operators

I am trying to replicate the behaviour of some of the built-in operator forms (for `Map`, `Apply` etc) but struggling to understand the way `Composition` works. For a concrete example:

```
list = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 11, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 11, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 10}

Map[Apply[Rule]]@list

%: {1 -> 10, 2 -> 11, 3 -> 11, 4 -> 10}
```

produces the result I was looking for in this case.

My question is how to replicate the composition of operator forms above. This naive attempt doesn't work as intended and produces an error message:

```
Map@*Apply@*Rule@list
```

Rule::argr: Rule called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected.

```
%: Map[Apply[Rule[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 11, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 11, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 10}]]]
```

I've tried various combinations of parentheses to control the evaluation to avail - the example I started with appears to build an operator form of the composition of `Apply` and `Rule` then maps it over the list input but that is not what the composition I attempted does.

So, how to produce the same with `Composition` or other constructs?

I'm asking really to try and get a fuller understanding of these types of construction work.

Comment: You could certainly do `(Map @* Apply @ Rule) @ list`, but `Rule @@@ list` is much more appropriate here.

Comment: @J.M. yes, you're right - I suppose what I'm getting at is why that isn't equivalent to `Composition[Map,Apply,Rule]@list`

Comment: Note: `Map@*Apply@*Rule` and `Map @* Apply @ Rule` are different

Comment: Look at what happens if you wrap each function name in `HoldForm[]`: `HoldForm[Map] @* HoldForm[Apply] @* HoldForm[Rule] @ HoldForm[list]` vs. `(HoldForm[Map] @* HoldForm[Apply] @ HoldForm[Rule]) @ HoldForm[list]`